# Bean method getting invoked randomly from action property

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, javabeans

I have the following in my JSP which is a popup window invoked from JSF page.

```xml
<h:commandButton id="cmd" value="Click" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('frm_name:hiddenInput').value=test();"
    action="#{bean.actionClick}" />
```

and in test() method of javascript I have

```
opener.focus();
opener.location.href = opener.location;
self.close();    
return hidValues;
```

Problem I am facing is upon selecting values from JSP popup window, action method of backing bean is not being called everytime, sometimes it is getting invoked, sometimes it doesn't.

I had doubt whether this is due to cache so I added the following in JSP popup

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

However even after adding not to cache the JSP page, still action method of bean is not getting invoked, like I mentioned earlier, sometimes it is getting invoked, sometimes t doesn't.

How could I resolve this problem?

My JSF version 1.1, page scope is session.

Comment: Could some one kindly provide some help? or @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is the window is closing before submit, you can close the window after the submit is done, you can do it putting a variable on your bean and read it on javascript while your page is loading

```
<script>

if( ${bean.canClose} ) {
 self.close()
}
</script>
```

so after your action method is invoked the page reloads and close it self